Terminal application has very high "12 hr Power" value in Activity Monitor
Basically I started the Terminal application but did not use it at all.
And since then I see Terminal had even higher "12 hr Power" than a browser!
What could it be possible?

Terminal with zsh and Oh My Zsh.


I use bash so I don't have an intimate knowledge of "Oh My Zsh" but according to the description on their website it adds "thousands of helpful functions, helpers, plugins [and] themes" so it's possible that the shell is "working" although you don't interact with it. Try disabling "Oh My Zsh" by commenting out source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh from your ~/.zshrc (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137187 for details) and checking if the energy usage improves. If that's the case, you could configure "Oh My Zsh" differently to reduce its energy footprint.

@jaume But most of the CPU time isn't being used by zsh, it's being used by the Terminal application itself. That presumably means something that's updating the terminal display.

The 12 hr power is a synthetic measurement and I wouldn’t worry about it except to notice things. In your case, you now know to keep an eye on terminal and let it ride another 6 or 12 hours and see if this was an anomaly or there’s even something to learn. My suspicion is it generated a lot of idle wakeups and in the absence of any other meaningful CPU use by other apps, dominated the scoreboard. Are you seeing this on battery or after a restart?

You are certainly right, CPU usage is low, but other factors like network activity and disk I/O influence the energy impact score. Since the only thing running is zsh, it makes sense to take a closer look at the shell. Apart from disabling "Oh My Zsh" as mentioned in my previous comment, you could, as a further troubleshooting step, configure Terminal to use bash (/bin/bash) and see if the 12-hr power usage changes.

I disabled oh my zsh and reboot the computer. Lets see for another day.

after restart and running for few days (w/o Oh My Zsh)  Terminal shows only less than 1 impact... Now I will install Oh My Zsh to try again. Though strange enough.
